# Rename [shadow-of-mordor] → [middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Monolith Productions' two latest games set in *The Lord of the Rings* universe are *[Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth:_Shadow_of_Mordor)* and *[Middle-earth: Shadow of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth:_Shadow_of_War)*. However, the tags of these two games are inconsistently named as [shadow-of-mordor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-mordor) and [middle-earth-shadow-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth-shadow-of-war).

Given that [middle-earth-shadow-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth-shadow-of-war) already has [shadow-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-war) as a synonym, I suggest that we rename the tag for *Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor* to its full name in order to match:

- [shadow-of-mordor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-mordor) → [middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor)

Since [the tag synonym system is completely broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/191265), we'll need a mod to show us the way.

[image: One does not simply rename [shadow-of-mordor]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done:

- [shadow-of-mordor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-mordor) → [middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor)